# Xamarin form: How to change the back button color

Tags: xamarin, colors, navigation

How do i change the back button of the navigation bar on xamarin form on both iOS and android? There was text color but can't find for back button

Comment: Hi, do you mean the background color of back button or the text color of back button ?

Comment: any solution? (for text color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question but @adamm answer works ,to change the Backbutton color .

You also can do this from Recources ,@Jessie Zhang gave me the solution.

```
     <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- Colors -->
        <Color x:Key="defaultBackbuttonColor">Red</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Yellow">#ffd966</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And in cs after   InitializeComponent();

```
Color color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["defaultBackbuttonColor"];
        NavigationPage.SetIconColor(this, color);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Xamarin.Forms version 4.6.0, you can do something like this:

```
NavigationPage.SetIconColor(this, Color.FromHex("#000000"));
```

I'm putting that after calling `InitializeComponent()`.